# Overflow on my webpage, why is it doing this?

Tags: html, css, overflow

On my webpage (which I'm still editing), there is an overflow on the right for some reason and I've looked at the code and I can't see where it is coming from? The css is currently in the index.html document as a style so it should be easy for you to look at it.

Here: [www.thejonty.co.uk](http://www.thejonty.co.uk/)
If on chrome... view-source:www.thejonty.co.uk

Your help is much appreciated - I'm not a fluent coder but I know my way around.
Thanks!

Comment: `<center>` in HTMl5? Use auto on left and right margins instead.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

Your footer has a `width` of `100%` and a `padding` of `20px`.
This makes a total of `40px` of overflow.

You may try using `padding: 20px 0;` which removes the unnecessary padding on the left and right side.

Answer (score 1):

Its your `<footer>`-Element that has a `width: 100%;` and a `padding: 20px;`.

You should wrap your copyright note within a `<p>` element and add the `padding: 20px;` to those p.

Something like this:

```
footer {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;

}

footer p {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; ...</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is  with footer.
When I removed footer there is no overflow.

Just remove Padding from footer style or set only padding top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remvove the `padding:20px` from footer and everthing is fine